# Discrete subspace of $\Bbb{R}$ is countable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Show that any discrete subspace of $\Bbb{R}$ with usual topology is countable.

Let $U$ be a discrete subspace of $\Bbb{R}$, for each $x\in U$ choose an interval with rational endpoints $(a_x,b_x)$ containing $x$ and if $y$ is distinct from $x$ then choose distinct $(a_y,b_y)$. Now consider the map $(a_x,b_x)\mapsto x$ , this map is surjective and since collection of intervals with rational endpoints is countable range must be countable i.e. $U$ is countable.Is it correct?

Comment: It's the right idea, but you should be more careful in showing that you can choose the intervals $(a_x, b_x)$ to be distinct as $x$ ranges over $U$. (This is where the assumption that $U$ is discrete is involved.)

Comment: I think using Hausdorff property we can always choose distinct nbds?

Comment: But all the neighborhoods you construct have to be distinct; Hausdorff spaces only guarantee that you can find distinct neighborhoods for a given pair of points. What happens with your argument if you try to reproduce it for, say, $[0, 1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own proof is *almost* there. You haven't really used the discreteness (it seems now that you claim this can be done for any subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but these are not all countable!).

So for each $x \in U$ pick $(a_x, b_x)$ with rational endpoints **such that** $(a_x , b_x) \cap U = \{x\}$. This uses that $\{x\} \subset U$ is open in $U$, which is the definition of being discrete.

Now, if $(a_x, b_x) = (a_y, b_y)$, intersect with $U$ to get $\{x\} = \{y\}$ or $x=y$. Now every point of $U$ is guaranteed to have a different rational interval...